# Корректно ли в модели использовать Set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, best-practice, моделирование

Мне необходимо было смоделировать структуру из предметной области, как объект в Python. Допустим это был кинофильм, имеющий название (на английском языке), и список людей (элементы существующего класса Actor), играющих главные роли.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Set

from project.actor import Actor

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Film:
    name: str
    starring: Set[Actor]
```

За данную реализацию я подвергся критике со стороны более старших и опытных коллег. Произошло это из-за использования Set вместо ожидаемого List. Насколько я помню (старался запомнить) аргументов было тверждение, что List - это более естественная и понятная структура, которая выполняет роль "контейнера". При моделировании стоит пользоваться для упрощения читаемости кода.

С предметной точки зрения набор актёров, играющих главные роли (атрибут 'starring'), **неупорядочен** (можно упорядочить по экранному времени или по алфавиту, но это не делается), он **не изменяем** (элементы типа Film создаются единожды при запуске сервиса и не меняются), и он **без дубликатов** (допущение, что один человек может играть только одну роль).

Я действительно видел очень редкое использование структур Tuple и Set (а уж тем более FrozenSet) даже там, где они могли быть использованы вместо List. С чем это связано? Есть ли какие-то соглашения по поводу использование стандартных структур? Быть может есть какие-то best practices? Замечали ли Вы подобное?

P.S Если быть совсем честным, вместо Set (допускающего добавление нового элемента) хотелось даже использовать FrozenSet, но его использование видел только в обучающих курсах, поэтому остановился.

Comment: Вопрос о мнениях. Но по-моему множество отлично подходит. К примеру, можно легко получать пересечения актерского состава между картинами для составления каких-нибудь жанровых карт или для формирования механизма рекомендаций. Но надо знать весь требуемый функционал для принятия решения.

Comment: Если "старшие и опытные коллеги" работают с вами на одном проекте, то в рамках проекта лучше делать как они говорят - меньше будет проблем. Но вообще, на мой взгляд, set здесь вполне уместен. FrozenSet тоже хороший вариант.

Answer (score 0):

*Касательно редкого использования структур Tuple и Set*

Использование многими кодерами по умолчанию именно списков скорей всего связано с тем, что `set` и `tuple`, на первый взгляд, являются под-типами списков. По крайней мере на "собесах" постоянно получаю след. определения - "сет - ну список, где хранятся только уникальные элементы", "кортеж - ну список, который не изменяем - можно пихнуть в словарь".

*Есть ли какие-то соглашения по поводу использование стандартных структур?*

Если они есть, то "танцуют" от прикладной задачи. Структуры данных выбирают в зависимости от решаемой задачи и принятых политик в организации/проекте. Понадобился например словарь, но не простой, а чтобы порядок внутри сохранял, обращаемся к встроенному модулю `my_dict = collections.OrderedDict`, потребовалось, что-то совсем извращённое, создаём свой класс с описанием custom-ной структуры данных. Бывает и так, если в конторе всё любят в деревьях хранить - придётся познакомиться с этой структурой - если собрались дальше там работать.

*Best practices*

Понимание сущности структур данных, какие они бывают, зачем нужны - этих знаний должно быть достаточно для повседневной работы.

*По вашей ситуации*

По мне классика "со своим уставом в чужой монастырь". Коллеги открыли ваш код и такие: "Он собрал актёров в сет, зачем в сет... блин что там за метод чтоб добавить элемент, походу не `append`. Чел прочитал вчера про структуры данных, наверное, решил вот в нашем супер хайлоуд приложении по-трениться в их выборе. У нас всё в списках и здесь тож будет список. `Отменить pull request` - клик".